# How to set node id as SKU id

Tags: commerce, nodes

I am using drupal commerce for e-commerce site. When node(product) is created SKU id of the product must be node id. How can I achieve it. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal Commerce products are ***entities***, not nodes. If you're looking for a product's SKU to be automatically set to the created product's id, there's the [Commerce AutoSKU module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_autosku) which allows you to use tokens (e.g. `[product:product-id]`) to automatically create SKUs.

One caveat from the project however:

> If you decide to use the [product:product-id] token, you should be
>   aware that this will cause any new products to be saved twice. This
>   shouldn't be an issue for most people, but if you have rules in place
>   for when a product is saved, you may not want to use this token.